# Intro image-background and footer image-background are offset

Tags: html, css

I want to have my footer and intro to have the same background but when I do it, it has the footer background image slightly offset. Is this because the picture on the intro has to be scaled up to accommodate for the height of the intro? Here is my code.

Intro HTML

```
<header class="intro">
    <div class="intro-body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h1 class="brand-heading">Contact</h1>
                    <a href="#main" class="page-scroll"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-4x"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Footer HTML

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-5 social-media">
                <a href="http://twitter.com" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter btn-large">
                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 social-media">
                <a href="http://facebook.com" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook btn-large">
                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Intro CSS

```
.intro {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 100px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: url(../img/intro-bg.jpg) no-repeat bottom center fixed;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

.intro .intro-body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.intro .intro-body .brand-heading {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.intro .intro-body .intro-text {
    font-size: 18px;
}

@media(min-width:767px) {
    .intro {
        height: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

    .intro .intro-body .brand-heading {
        font-size: 80px;
    }

    .intro .intro-body .intro-text {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you not narrow down the code to only the relevant CSS/HTML ?

Comment: Can no one figure it out? I will try to get rid of some of the code

Comment: I figured it out, i just changed all the footer css to the intro css and changed "intro" to "footer" and changed height.